# How do I make my response upto the required standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, serialization

So, I have a backend rails application running which is responding for a particular request as follows

`{"id": 68,"name": "name","email": "email"}`

But in ember, I'm getting this error

```
Error: Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
* One or more of the following keys must be present: "data", "errors", "meta".
at Object.assert (index.js:163)
at normalizeResponseHelper (-private.js:7428)
at -private.js:13291
at Backburner._run (backburner.js:1010)
at Backburner._join (backburner.js:986)
at Backburner.join (backburner.js:757)
at -private.js:13287
at tryCatcher (rsvp.js:335)
at invokeCallback (rsvp.js:506)
at publish (rsvp.js:492)
```

I tried wrapping everything under a 'data' array, then I got this error

```
Error: Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
* Top level of a JSON API document must be an object
at Object.assert (index.js:163)
at normalizeResponseHelper (-private.js:7428)
at -private.js:13291
at Backburner._run (backburner.js:1010)
at Backburner._join (backburner.js:986)
at Backburner.join (backburner.js:757)
at -private.js:13287
at tryCatcher (rsvp.js:335)
at invokeCallback (rsvp.js:506)
at publish (rsvp.js:492)
```

How do I normalize it all and where, backend or frontend?

update: I made a hash response = {:data=>@user}, and then returned response.to_json I got this

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Encountered a resource object with an undefined type (resolved resource using (unknown))
at Object.assert (index.js:163)
at Class._normalizeResourceHelper (json-api.js:183)
at Class._normalizeDocumentHelper (json-api.js:133)
at Class._normalizeResponse (json-api.js:228)
at Class.normalizeSingleResponse (json.js:407)
at Class.normalizeSaveResponse (json.js:393)
at Class.normalizeCreateRecordResponse (json.js:351)
at Class.normalizeResponse (json.js:232)
at normalizeResponseHelper (-private.js:7421)
at -private.js:13291
```

Comment: Try { id: 68, name: 'name', email: 'email'}

Comment: Tried, it said unidentified 'i' at 1, something like that

Comment: when you "wrapped everything under a 'data' array" what did that look like?

Comment: I did response = "{\"data\":[#{@user}]}".to_json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for `ember-data` is to use the [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) standard. This isn't a requirement though so you have two options:

1) You can modify the output on your server to meet that standard, there are some libraries to do this for you, but I haven't gone that route so I'm not up to date on what is current.

2) You can tell ember to parse your response differently, you do this by customizing the `adapter` for you application.

Our API looks a lot like yours and in my `app/adapters/application.js` file I have:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
});
```

Documented at https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/. This is a fully supported way to customize ember to meet your needs and other tools like `ember-cli-mirage` also offer support for this less structured REST adapter approach.

Answer (score 2):

So, the only way I was able to make this work was by strictly adhering to the JSON standards.

I changed my response to be exactly like in the format specified in the ember guides

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "user",
        "id": "123",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Jeff",
            "email": "Jeff@abc.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Still looking for a way to override it

Comment: jrjohnson’s answer should help with what you are after

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ember, but going from the error messages you have provided there's two constraints that have been highlighted.

- The top level of the JSON must be an object, and
- that object must have one of these keys present: "data", "errors", "meta"

Given that information I would try returning this:

```
{"data": {"id": 68,"name": "name","email": "email"} }
```

Comment: Fixed the 2nd one, how do I do the 1st one? I always thought json is text based